# Control Android device from PC with linux

Tags: android, remote-access, mouse, keyboard

I know there's a lot of similar questions, but this is why it's not a duplicate:

- I've checked most of the questions
- I need to control the device from Linux
- I don't need shared screen

I'd like to see something similar to Synergy for multiple computers (http://synergy-project.org/). It behaves like an additional screen, so you can use one mouse and see it moving on Windows laptop even it's connected to Linux PC.

Is there any app that simulates Android device as an additional screen so you can use your mouse and keyboard and see the mouse moving on your Android? I prefer not to use any apps that grabs the phone screen and sends it back to the PC, because it's rather slow. I keep my device close to the laptop so this is just an unnecessary feature.

Comment: There are VNC servers available for Android, that may do what you want.

Comment: Bullet pint 3 "•I don't need shared screen"!, seems to contradict " app that simulates Android device as an additional screen  ..."

Comment: If you don't need the screen, then SSH is the obvious answer

Comment: @Mawg by 'shared screen' I meant: I don't need the screen of android device to be displayed on my computer's screen. Hope that explains the confusion?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Splashtop Extended Display HD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splashtop.remote.xdisplay). It can be used to extend your display from your computer.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot download this app to any of my devices: "This app is incompatible with all of your devices."

Comment: So I found a possible answer for you on a sister site. http://askubuntu.com/questions/28608/how-do-you-use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-display